# NaN Result with unique squares

Tags: javascript, nan

I am writing a function in Javascript that would take in a number, then return how many squares there are in a square with sides that long. For example, passing through 1 would give you one, 2 would give you 5, 3 would give you 14 and so forth. The problem is, I'm getting a result of Nan. I'm not sure where it would have gotten anything besides a number from.

```
function a (n)
{
if (n > 0)
{
    var total = n*n;
    total += a(n-1);
    return (total);
}
}
document.write(a(10));
```

Comment: Look at the value your function returns when `n == 0`.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not sure where it would have gotten anything besides a number from.

Your base case is missing, it returns `undefined`. Try

```
function a(n) {
    if (n > 0)
        return n*n + a(n-1);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the `if (n > 0)` When this is not true your function returns `void`. So return `0` on your else.

```
function a (n)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        var total = n*n;
        total += a(n-1);
        return total;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
console.log(a(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have two good answers. I just want to make you aware of writing in a more Object Oriented style. If things get more complicated it is easier to group the variables and functions together and keep them toghether away from all your other stuff. I would write something like this to keep it organized:

```
var a = {

    total: 0,

    sides: function (n) {

        if (n > 0) {
            this.total = n * n;
            this.total += this.sides(n - 1);
            return this.total;
        } else {
            return 0
        }

    }

}

a.sides(5);
alert(a.total);
```